# Read cell data from excel sheet with python 3.6.x with xlrd library

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

This is my sample code

```
import xlrd

file_location=("/home/deep/Desktop/Book1.xlsx")
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
first=sheet.cell_value(1,1)

print(first)
```

**but i get following error into that**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/deep/ws/xcx.py", line
>   6, in 
>       workbook=xlrd.workbook(file_location) AttributeError: module 'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'

Answer (score 1):

As per your error message ,

```py
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/deep/ws/xcx.py", line 6, in workbook=xlrd.workbook(file_location) AttributeError: module'xlrd' has no attribute 'open_workbook'
```

I guess you've made a typo error, It says

`workbook=xlrd.workbook(file_location)`

It must have been:

`workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)`

xlrd works fine for me !! Just tried it !!

Answer (score 0):

`open_workbook` is perfectly fine to use. But at the last line, you should use:

```
first=sheet.cell(1,1) 
print(first.value)
```